# Can't save a radar chart using RStudio and got a blank chart

Tags: r

I just start coding on RStudio, and I tried to draw a radar chart from a csv. The thing is, I want to use a loop to produce all my charts together, and save them in the same file, but all I get is 32 blank pictures.

This is a screenshot of my csv:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pafdp.png)

The following is part of my code:

```
for (i in c(1:32)){
  
  selected_data <- scaled_data[i, ]
  
  chart_name <- paste("Radar_chart", i)
  
  # Create filename
  filename <- paste("radar_chart_p", i, ".png", sep = "")
  
  #Copy png into file
  png(filename, width = 800, height = 600)
  
  radar_chart <- ggradar(selected_data, base.size = 15, plot.title = chart_name)
  
  dev.off()
  
}
```

Hope someone can help me with it!

Comment: Hi and welcome @pandapanda! Please dont upload your data as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12109788), but instead edit your question to include reproducible code. Some tips on doing that are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for (i in 1:32) {
  selected_data <- scaled_data[i, ]
  
  chart_name <- paste("Radar_chart", i)
  
  # Create the radar chart
  radar_chart <- ggradar(selected_data, base.size = 15, plot.title = chart_name)
  
  # Create filename
  filename <- paste("radar_chart_p", i, ".png", sep = "")
  
  # Save the radar chart as a PNG file
  ggsave(filename, plot = radar_chart, width = 8, height = 6, dpi = 300)
}
```

Comment: You welcome, remember to give an upvote